# How to get NSString between two words?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have NSString in the following format

`NSString *string1 = @"webservices/employee/1";`    and another string with
`NSString *string2 = @"webservices/manaager/1";`

I want to get the string in between "werbservice/" and "/1" using a common method.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] objectAtIndex:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method for deviding the string `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator`

use like this

```
-(NSString *)returnComponent:(NSString *)str
{
   NSString *returnString=[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] objectAtIndex:1];

return returnString;
}
```

Comment: There really isn't a reason to create that NSMutableArray there. The NSArray you get back from -[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:] will do just fine.

Comment: Your code doesn't modify the array. There's definitely overhead to creating another  copy of an array that already exists.

Comment: Ok now it is fine with out mutable array.